# Remove an object from an array and then delete

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller

I am building a system in the MVC design pattern. I need to create a series of controllers. Later I may want to be able to remove these controllers from memory when they are no longer needed. The controller is created using the new keyword so I had the problem of how to store references to the objects. I decided to use an array. When I create they are added to an array, when I destroy I loop through the array and remove. I want to make sure that I am not leaking memory. Assuming I am not creating other references to the controller objects would this effectively make them candidates for garbage collection:

```
//creating the objects and storing them
//create image controller & modelfor each image (model injected as a dependency)

 for (var i = 0; i < imageData.galleryImages.length; i++) {
 imageControllerArray.push( new ImageController(someParam, new model()));
 };

//here I want to destroy the controllers
 while(imageControllerArray.length){
        imageControllerArray.pop(); //would this do it?
        //delete imageControllerArray.pop(); //What about this?
        // imageControllerArray.pop().destroy() //where each controller deletes itself
    }
```

What is the best way to approach this problem? Any advice? I get the idea that what I need to do is delete any references to the controllers rather than the objects themselves. I am concerned that my approach may be creating the objects on some global space and so just deleting the array reference won't actually free the object up for garbage collection.

Comment: Javascript is garbage collected. Once nothing points to your object any more (i.e. nothing in the current scope or global object `window` points to anything which points to anything which ... your object), it will be removed (at some time, possibly not immediately). You can sometimes help the garbage collector (relevant to old IE) by `null`ing things. Problems usually only arise when you are mixing javascript objects with DOM nodes (especially callbacks)

Comment: You can test if your object is being collected using Google Chrome's developer tools (Profiles -> Heap Snapshot). Take a few snapshots before/after doing things and see if anything is surviving too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the object being removed from the array catch the popped item from the array and you'll have removed the item from the array and now can apply whatever else it is that you need to do with it, like checking to see if any other object points to the popped array item.

If anything points to the popped item being removed from the array you can bet it will live forever, until the item pointing to the popped array item is deleted or removed.

```
  while(imageControllerArray.length){

     var myArrayItem = imageControllerArray.pop();

       if(myArrayItem.otherObj){

       delete myArrayItem.otherObj;

      //you're now good to go
};
  };
```